# JQuery Ajax/getJSON issue on select to change height accordingly

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, getjson

I am trying to pull the room information with a *JQuery's* .**getJSON** or .**ajax** methods.

It works fine in **Opera** and **Firefox**.

The problem arises in **Chrome** and **IE**, and the **select** does not change its height to the new amount of elements, showing me **only first element in the select box**.

In order for me to see the rest I can scroll within one element's height, or take focus off the select by clicking somewhere else on the page, and selecting a select option again would show the correct height (of let's say of 20 elements/options).

I think it has to do with timing or **.html()** method, because problem arises when I am populating my "room_id" select. Maybe the DOM structure does not gets updated properly after the ajax call?

```
<select name="room_id" id="room_id" class="textbox">
<option value="..." capacity="...">Select a room from the list...</option>
</select>
```

JQuery (I tried **getJSON()** before, same thing).
Sorry for messy indentation, doing it first time :s

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
...
$('#room_id').click(function() {
    fetchRooms();
}).change();
...
function fetchRooms() {
   $('#room_id').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
   $.ajax({
  url:'here is my link...',
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,                                // tried with true before
  success: function(data) 
      {
    var $items='';
    var $is_selected = false;

            // populating items if ajax returns data
    for (var $i=0; $i < data.length; $i++)
    {
        var $selected = (data[$i]['room_id'] == '<?=$event->room_id;?>' ? 'selected="selected"':'');
        if ($selected != '') { $is_selected = true; }
        $items += '<option value="'+data[$i]['room_id']+'" '+$selected+' capacity="'+data[$i]['capacity']+'">'+data[$i]['room_name']+'</option>';
    }


            if (data.length == 0)
        $items = '<option value="">(No rooms are available)</option>';

            // populating select with items
    $('#room_id').html($items);

}
 }); ... } ...
```

**EDIT**: As suggested by **ShankarSangoli** I tried to fire **setTimeout**, but it didn't help.

**Remark**: In IE it looks as following: I click on select, item gets selected and the list
with items closes. (Like if I selected the first option and that's it).
In Firefox and Opera, it looks how I wanted it to be: I click on select, drop-down menu with
items/options appear with first one that was pulled by ajax pre-highlighted.
In Chrome it is what I described above, the height of drop-down is of one item and first item is pre-selected.

```
$('#room_id').click(function() {
// 
setTimeout(function() {
    fetchRooms();
}, 500);

}).change();
```

*I have to do it on click rather than on change for other reasons, just ignore that please :p*

Comment: It turned out to be that browsers treat click event differently. Instead of click I can use other events to deal with the problem, like on hover, which gets called prior to click.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your problem here is my solution.

Execute the ajax call after certain delay on select change, this will give time to close the select box. When you make a ajax call right after select change it does not close immediately specially in IE browser. Try this it will work fine.

```
$('select').change(function(){

   setTimeout(function(){
       //Do ajax call here
   }, 200);//200 ms should be fine
});
```